# Conditional Rendering in React Page Refresh Only Happens with Ctrl + F5

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to React so please bear with me.

I have a main component with conditional rendering. On logout I call the handleLogout method to log out. This works in that it clears the token, but my page will then not refresh without pressing ctrl + f5.

I have tried using the methods below in handleLogout without success:

```
this.ForceUpdate();
this.setState(this.state);
this.props.history.replace('/login');
```

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Stuff from "./Stuff";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import LoginForm from './forms/LoginForm';
import RegisterForm from './forms/RegisterForm';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

import AuthService from './auth/AuthService';
import withAuth from './auth/withAuth';

const Auth = new AuthService();


class Main extends Component {

  handleLogout(){
    Auth.logout()
    //this.setState({shouldupdate: true});
    //alert(this.state);
    //this.ForceUpdate()
    //this.setState(this.state);
    //this.props.history.replace('/login');
  }


  render() {
    if(Auth.loggedIn()) {
      return (
        <HashRouter>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={2}>
                <ul className="header">
                  <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/" onClick={this.handleLogout()}>Logout</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                <Route path="/logout" component={LoginForm}/>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </HashRouter>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <HashRouter>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={2}>
                <ul className="header">
                  <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/register">Register</NavLink></li>
                  <li><NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink></li>
                </ul>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                <Route path="/register" component={RegisterForm}/>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </HashRouter>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default withAuth(Main);
```

UPDATED CODE FOR SETTING LOGIN:

My code looks as the following for updating the login state by passing a function as a property to the child component. When I login I get a popup stating this.props.setLoggedIn is not a function.

My render function has:

```
<Route path="/login" render={(props) => <LoginForm {...props} setLoggedIn={this.setLoggedin}/>}/>
```

The setLoggedIn function looks like:

```
  setLoggedIn() {
    this.setState({loggedin: true});
  }
```

The login function which makes use of this in the LoginForm class is as follows:

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

    this.Auth.login(this.state.username,this.state.password)
    .then(res =>{
       this.props.setLoggedIn();
       this.props.history.push("/");
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        alert(err);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save login status in state, when the user logout update the value.

```
state = {
  isLoggedIn: false,
};

componentDidMount = () => {

  const isLoggedIn = Auth.loggedIn(); // check if user is logged in

    this.setState({
      isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn
    });
}

handleLogout = () => {
  Auth.logout();

  this.setState({
    isLoggedIn: false, // update login status
  })
}
```

in your render use `this.state.isLoggedIn`

```
render() {
  if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={2}>
              <ul className="header">
                <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/" onClick={this.handleLogout()}>Logout</NavLink></li>
              </ul>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
              <Route path="/logout" component={LoginForm}/>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col xs={2}>
              <ul className="header">
                <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/register">Register</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink></li>
              </ul>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
              <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
              <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
              <Route path="/register" component={RegisterForm}/>
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Since adding the componentDidMount it seems to be causing the server to slow right down and I have to stop it before I can run things again. I'm alerting the this.state.isLoggedIn variable, but it still shows as false.

Comment: `componentDidMount` does nothing but call the same function you are calling in render, I don't see how it;s slowing down the server.

Comment: @RLBChrisBriant please `console.log(isLoggedIn)` inside componentDidMount, just after `Auth.loggedIn()`.

Comment: If I console.log the two values for this.state.logged in and Auth.loggedIn() then I get true for both after logging in and false when starting out.

Comment: yes `this.state.isLoggedIn: false` by default, if you are logged in it will be set to true, based on the value returned from `Auth.loggedIn()`.

Comment: I am getting this warning: Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Comment: this `onClick={this.handleLogout()}` might be the problem, as you are calling the function.

Comment: change it to `onClick={() => this.handleLogout()}`

Comment: Thanks, it now refreshes when clicking on logout. Now I need to get it to refresh after logging in, but I am struggling to understand how to do that because the login class is a child component.

Comment: then pass `isLoggedIn` as a prop

Comment: after you login what happens?

Comment: It doesn't refresh after logging on.

Comment: to solve this you need to pass a value from login to parent component?

Comment: I've created a simple example on how to update a state of parent component within a child component https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bdg1tr

Comment: Thanks, the example is useful, I can understand how it is working, but I am getting problems when trying this from the within the route tag. I have posted an update to the code I have tried.

Comment: I think I got it working, there was a typo with "setLoggedIn". I had the 'I' as lowercase in one instance. I will check in the morning and then confirm that it is working. Many thanks.

Comment: Use `<Route path="/login" component={() => <LoginForm setLoggedIn={this.setLoggedin} />}/>`, I've updated the example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bdg1tr

Comment: Many thanks for your help, it now all seems good. I can mark this as the answer. Do you want me to edit your answer with the actual code as it looks?

Answer (score 0):

First set local state variable in a state object like .

```
state = {shouldupdate:false};
```

set your shouldupdate variable according to auth on mounting .

```
componentDidMount = () => {
const shouldupdate = Auth.loggedIn(); // this wil check if user is logged in

this.setState({shouldupdate: shouldupdate}); // here we setting state a/c to auth on initial render
}
```

Then instead of using AUTH.login() inside if block , use your state variable shouldUpdate.
Inside your logout function set state like below.

```
 handleLogout(){
    Auth.logout()
    this.setState({shouldupdate: true});
    //alert(this.state);
    //this.ForceUpdate()
    //this.setState(this.state);
    //this.props.history.replace('/login');
  }
```

And inside render use it like .

```
    render() {
    if(this.state.shouldupdate) {
      return (...)}
       else {
      }
```

React only re renders if there is a change in a state . And it seems your AUTH.logout function has not have any work to do with state

Comment: this won't work, let's say the user is logged in , `shouldupdate:false` is set to false by default, then the else part will be executed even though the user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know . I've updated my answer